# Do I have to restart my Server for java.security file changes to have an effect?

Tags: java, java-security

Our security program flagged our Java-server for using static key ciphers. Thus I added these algorithms to the `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms` inside of `java.security`:

```
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
```

Because the servers are only scanned once a week, I cannot check the security portal to see if the changes were applied.
Do I have to restart the Java-server, reload the `java.security` file somehow or do these changes directly apply?

Comment: I don't think that the JVM dynamically reloads these settings. Since this might be a security problem, why take any chances and not restart the Java processes?

Comment: The java process is a highly critical system and downtime is to be avoided. I will try to restart it today and organize a downtime.